# Create Subtags on XML from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, namespaces

I'm trying to generate an XML from SQL Server with subtags and, at the same time, with Namespaces. 
At the moment I've done this script on SQL

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as sii)  
SELECT TOP 1 ID as 'sii:ID'
            ,[NAME] as 'sii:NAME'
            ,[SURNAME] as 'sii:SURNAME'
            ,[PRICE] as 'sii:PRICE'
FROM [dbo].[EMPLOYEES]  
FOR XML RAW ('sii:Envelope'), ELEMENTS
```

that generates this:

```
<sii:Envelope xmlns:sii="URI">
  <sii:ID>08AL</sii:ID>
  <sii:NAME>GEORGE</sii:NAME>
  <sii:SURNAME>AURON</sii:SURNAME>
  <sii:PRICE>1900.35</sii:PRICE>
</sii:Envelope>
```

but I'm having some problems when I want to envelop NAME & SURNAME into another category called FULL_NAME, like this:

```
<sii:Envelope xmlns:sii="URI">
  <sii:ID>08AL</sii:ID>
  <sii:FULL_NAME>
    <sii:NAME>GEORGE</sii:NAME>
    <sii:SURNAME>AURON</sii:SURNAME>
  </sii:FULL_NAME>
  <sii:PRICE>1900.35</sii:PRICE>
</sii:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `RAW`, but `PATH` when you are going to generate the XML. Here is the solution to the code provided above:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as sii)  
SELECT TOP 1 ID as 'sii:ID'
            ,[NAME] as 'sii:FULL_NAME/sii:NAME'
            ,[SURNAME] as 'sii:FULL_NAME/sii:SURNAME'
            ,[PRICE] as 'sii:PRICE'
FROM [dbo].[EMPLOYEES]  
FOR XML PATH('sii:Envelope'), ELEMENTS
```